# Vue Deployment - modules[moduleId] is undefined on page load

Tags: vue.js, d3.js, deployment, devops

Currently have an Azure pipeline that is watching the staging branch and building on changes using npm and Vue CLI 3. Everything has been working fine until there was a new merge and build, which caused the error `t[e] is undefined` to show up. I removed minification and saw that the error was `module[moduleId] is undefined` on page load. Everything runs fine locally, and everything had been running fine deployed prior to this.

There was a Vuetify plugin update that has since been reverted without change. I've also had this issue with the D3 library (which is currently in use), but I'm wondering if the issue is just that the building is no longer working in the pipeline, or if everything needs to be rebuilt from scratch or a cache needs to be cleared (I'm not a DevOps guy).

Anyone have any insight for an app suddenly breaking like this?

EDIT: Seems to be related to the d3 library. Any reason why it would work locally but not when deployed? And with no errors on building?

Comment: Could it be this issue: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/5429#issuecomment-463213127
What version of webpack are you using?